# aws secrets caching describeSecrets error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to implement a caching for the secrets stored in aws KMS, using [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/improve-availability-and-latency-of-applications-by-using-aws-secret-managers-python-client-side-caching-library/) blog post.

Locally when I test the code, the script runs fine. At the moment I am unsure if it fetches from KMS or use credentials from `~/.aws` folder. But when I push the code to kubernetes cluster and try to test their I get the error `no identity based policy allows the secretsmanager:DescribeSecret action`

Can somebody please help how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because your local code is using your ~/.aws credentials, which have rights to describe secrets `secretsmanager:DescribeSecret`.

Check if the permissions given to your kubernetes cluster have rights to describe secrets `secretsmanager:DescribeSecret`